Turning Common English Language errors into a teachable moment
Context:
I was assisting a younger member of my family with her English homework last night.
She is required to identify the errors in the passages below and correct the error identified.
She has recently been taught to identify common errors in the English Language. She continues to find it challenging to fully understand the language (even though she is a native speaker).  She also tends to think about the parts of speech within the English language in isolation, instead of appreciating how they interact with one another – to generate/ encode meaning.
I have some questions that I hope the community can help me with.
My immediate goal with her is to assist her with exercises like this which require her to make use of language awareness.

Can anyone suggest any methods or techniques I can use to achieve this goal?
To give you an example of what I’m dealing with. Here is an example: "commitment to elder people." She failed to spot the error. When I identified the error for her I asked her what part of speech modifies nouns (like people). I was rather concerned when she replied with adverb, instead of adjective. I can appreciate that she saw the -ly at the end of elderly and assumed it was an adverb. I then had to remind her that not all adverbs end in -ly and that the context should have given away the answer?

Are the errors (in red/bold) and corrections (show in the tables) … correct?
I was second guessing myself with some of these errors, so input from the community would be greatly appreciated.





Hello, Chris. ELU addresses single points of grammar etc; 'doing homework' is explicitly off-topic.  / That said, you've spotted quite a few errors and corrected them. One glaring omission is 'laying' where 'lying' should be used. But again,  the 'one of the boys who was/were' and the less/fewer debate have been addressed on ELU and are far from simple.

More specific questions about e.g. parts of speech or individual errors in that table would likely be on topic here, but the question as written is far too broad for this site.

This list has a mid-twentieth century flavor.  Old so-called rules.
